# Usage of articles: getting flu / getting a flu

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Should we say, "You are getting *a* flu." or "You are getting flu." ?

In an exercise in a grammar book, the answer is given as the latter case.
However, we normally say, "I have a headache," which involves using "a" here.
Why don't we say "getting a flu" instead of "getting flu"?

Comment: If you were to read some novels of the 1930s, you might meet 'getting a flu'  more commonly than 'getting flu'. But now it sounds very old-fashioned. Articles are bothersome things; it takes 70 years to learn how everybody uses them, and then you find that the rules have changed. / 'I have a backache' and 'I have backache' are probably about as popular. Or should that be unpopular?

Comment: I'd actually say "getting the flu".

Comment: @rjpond According to [GoogleNgrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=getting+flu%2Cgetting+a+flu%2Cgetting+the+flu&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgetting%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgetting%20the%20flu%3B%2Cc0), since 1994 it's the in thing even among Brits. But not the yuppie flu.

Answer (score 0):

*Flu* is considered as *uncountable* whereas *headache* is *countable*. The indefinite article **a/an** cannot be used before uncountable nouns.

> - **[flu](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/flu)** (fluː ) uncountable noun [oft the NOUN]
>
>   - **[headache](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/headache)** (hedeɪk ) Word forms: plural headaches
>
>     1. countable noun

Comment: But [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flu) has:  << flu (usually uncountable, plural flus) >>. 'Flu' is **usually** considered as uncountable, and best used as such nowadays.